# Concatenation inside a parameter

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to concatenate my increment variable inside the getElementById parameter.  I can concatenate using createElement using the increment value, however when I try to concatenate the variable inside getElementbyId, its a no go.

```
var newdiv = document.createElement("form");
            newdiv.setAttribute('id', 'form' + t);//t == increment
            newdiv.innerHTML = "<br/>" + t + Menu();
            $("newline").appendChild(newdiv);

alert(

document.getElementById("form" + t).innerHTML  //does not work
document.getElementById("form0").innerHTML   //needs to "look" like

)
```

Comment: Where is `t` defined? If you say `alert(t)` at that point what do you get?

Answer (score 0):

It's not totally clear what you're trying to do, but you can increment a variable in-place after using it's value by applying the `++` operator like so:

```javascript
var t = 0;
alert('OK: t=' + (t++)); // => alerts "OK: t=0"
alert('OK: t=' + (t++)); // => alerts "OK: t=1"
alert('OK: t=' + (t++)); // => alerts "OK: t=2"
```

Note that if you use the `++` operator before it's operand then it will increment *before* using the value:

```javascript
var u = 0;
alert('OK: u=' + (++u)); // => alerts "OK: u=1"
alert('OK: u=' + (++u)); // => alerts "OK: u=2"
alert('OK: u=' + (++u)); // => alerts "OK: u=3"
```